# WPF "Magic" in a PropertyGrid Control

Tags: wpf, propertygrid

I started a hobby project to learn about WPF and in my reasearch i stumpled upon this WPF PropertyGrid http://www.codeplex.com/wpg

I downloaded the source from http://wpg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx
, And started browsing through it, looks cool, and works. But for the life of me, I can't figure out HOW it works. The following questions is what I'm left with at first glance.

- How does it know what properties an object have?
- How does it render the control to edit a Value?
- How does it decide what control to render? (i'm guessing meta data descriptions on the properties)

I understand the DependancyProperties handles the dataexchange between new values.

- Where is the XAML or CodeBehind code that does all the magic?

There is lots of XAML code in the Default.xaml file, but as far as I can tell it is only styles and the looks that are defined there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - How does it know what properties an object have?

It uses [`System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) to determine the properties that a type has via [`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getproperties.aspx). A [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.aspx) provides a wealth of information about each property (e.g., [`PropertyDescriptor.IsReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.isreadonly.aspx) will tell you that a property is readonly). Further, using [`PropertyDescriptor.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.getvalue.aspx) and [`PropertyDescriptor.SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.setvalue.aspx), the values of properties can be obtained and written to.

> - How does it render the control to edit a Value?
> - How does it decide what control to render? (i'm guessing meta data descriptions on the properties)

It uses a custom control called a `PropertyGrid` which exposes an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of `Item`s. `Item` is merely a base class for the core model object which is `Property`. `Property` exposes the underlying type (`PropertyDescritor.PropertyType`) of the property and exposes the `PropertyDescriptor.GetValue` and `PropertyDescriptor.SetValue` methods via `Property.Value`. This, in turn, is what is bound to to enable the editing. [`DataTemplate`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) are the key here. A few CLR types have custom `DataTemplate`s that render the controls you see. For example, the `Boolean` type is rendered as a `CheckBox` while an `Enum` is rendered as a `ComboBox`. The default `DataTemplate` is a `TextBox`.

> - Where is the XAML or CodeBehind code that does all the magic?

The propensity of it is in `Themes\Default.xaml`.

The code can be summarized as thus. There is data (`Data\Property`) that encapsulates the information about properties of an object and provides a property (`Property.Value`) to read and write the value of a property. This data is exposed as an `ObservableCollection` in a custom control (`PropertyGrid`) which is rendered using `DataTemplate`s in `Themes\Default.xaml`.

> There is lots of XAML code in the Default.xaml file, but as far as I can tell it is only styles and the looks that are defined there.

Don't overlook the `DataTemplate`s.

Answer (score 4):

> - How does it know what properties an object have?

If it works the same way as the Windows Forms property grid, it does the following :

- if the object implements ICustomTypeDescriptor, obtain the properties from this interface (with the GetProperties method)
- otherwise, use reflection on the object's type (obj.GetType().GetProperties()

For the other questions... well, I haven't looked at the code, so I can't answer ;)